# Java unzip strange character (encoding?)

Tags: java, encoding, zip, java-io

when I unzip a zip file in java, I see a strange behaviour with stressed character in the files name.

Syso :

> Add File user : L'equipe Technique -- Folder : spec eval continue --
>   File Name : Capture d’écran 2013-05-29 à 17.24.03.png

If I print the String we didn't see any issue but when I display the char from the String, I've got this :

> C a p t u r e    d ’ e  ́ c r a n

Instead of :

> C a p t u r e    d ’ é c r a n

It causes trouble when writing the string in database. I do not generate the archive but I have no problem opening it with my OS tools. It may be an encoding issue but I don't see how to solve it...

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ArchiveInputStream ais = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream(bis);

        ArchiveEntry entry = null;
        // Parcours des entrées de l'archive
        while((entry = ais.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Test one");
            // on va essayer de ne pas traiter les dossier
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                String[] filePath = entry.getName().split("/");
                List<String> filePathList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0; i<filePath.length; i++) {
                    filePathList.add(filePath[i]);
                }

                // on recupere le dossier qui doit contenir le fichier
                Folder targetFolder = getTargetFolder(filePathList.subList(0, filePathList.size()-1), rootFolder, user, scopeGroupId);

                String targetFileName = "";
                targetFileName = filePathList.get(filePathList.size()-1);

                //Ajout du fichier
                final int BUFFER = 2048;

                FileCacheOutputStream myFile = new FileCacheOutputStream();
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
                while ((count = ais.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    myFile.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                System.out.println("Add File user : "+user.getFullName()+" -- Folder : "+targetFolder.getName()+" -- File Name : "+targetFileName);
                addFile(user, targetFolder, targetFileName, myFile.getBytes());
            }
        }
```

Comment: "If I print the String we didn't see any issue but when I display the char from the String" What does this mean? How do you "display the char from the String"? I see that you do a `System.out.println`, but what is the `file.encoding` setting for Java, and what is the terminal you're printing it to using and expecting?

Comment: I "display the char from the String" with a loop using the string length and printing characters one by one. I thought that showing the way I printed these wasn't very interesting. As RealSkeptic pointed, it has nothing to do with encoding at the end. Only an accented character issue.

Comment: The way you print can matter because the problem can be in the data in the string, or in the way your terminal interprets the output from Java (are they using the same charset?), or in the font the terminal uses to display it. In this case, it was combining diacriticals vs. precombined characters and normalization is the answer, but in other cases it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accented characters can be expressed in more than one way in Unicode. You can have a *pre-combined* é, or a plain e followed by a *combining accent*.

In your case, the file name is built using the second method. If your database collation doesn't take this into account, or the database is not stored in Unicode, it may become a problem.

You can use the [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class to convert between the two forms. For example:

```
String normStr = Normalizer.normalize (origStr,Normalizer.Form.NFC);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is exactly what I was searching for. Problem solved !